# How to add search bar to Picker React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am really new to React Native and try to add a search bar to Picker , here is the package I used
`import {Picker} from '@react-native-picker/picker'`.
However I could not find any resource about this issue. Also I tried to use `react-native-dropdown-picker` package but it gives lots of error and cannot even build the project. Here is the my picker on code, and it works well. Can you help me to find a way to add search bar to this Picker?

```
        <Picker
        selectedValue={selectedValueVarlikTur}
        style={{ height: 50, width: 300,alignSelf:'center'}}
        itemStyle={{height: 44, fontSize:16}}
        onValueChange={(newValue) => setSelectedValuVarlikTur(newValue)}>

        { varlik_tur_arr.map((value,index) => {
             return <Picker.Item label={value} value={value} key={index} />}) }   

        </Picker>
```

Answer (score 0):

@iozy, Place the search bar UI just before the .map function. It will work for sure.

Comment: Where should I place exactly? I tried it before {varlik_tur_arr.map ... } part, however it wont work. Final  look like  ... onValueChange={(newValue) => setSelectedValuVarlikTur(newValue)}> <SearchBar
                placeholder="Type Here..."
                onChangeText={text => setSearchSon(text)}
                value={seachSon}
            /> {varlik_tur_arr. map ..... } Sorry for my question but I am really new and try to understand the basics.

Comment: [ http://aboutyusata.blogspot.com/2018/07/picker-with-search-bar.html ]
Maybe this link helps you but, You have to switch to a different module.